# TYPO3 language switch in action

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I use TYPO3 8.7.3 and my own extension.
So far, I was able to use the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['language']` variable to switch in extbase to another language.
This is actually not possible.
Is there a new way to switch between languages in the action of a controller?
Important for me to create Mails and PDF throw:
`\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate`

BR

Daniel

Comment: Nobody can help?

Answer (score 1):

In your action you can check for sys_language_uid like this:

```
if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid == 0 ) {
    // Your English text
} else if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid == 1) {
    // Your German text
} else {
    // Your English text            
}
```

... when language is set via typoscript:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
config {
    ...
    sys_language_uid = 0
    sys_language_isocode = en
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
    ...
    sys_language_uid = 1
    sys_language_isocode = de
}
[global]
```